# Flyway- how to configure transaction timeout for migration only rather than whole application

Tags: java, spring, flyway, alter-table

I am strugling with flyway and altering table adding new column. Table contains 500k+ rows and my datasource transaction timeout is set to 10s. Unfortunately altering table takes more than 10s and this is the issue. I would like to increase transaction timeout for flyway only rather than for whole application. I have searched google and documentation and I haven't found any tip to do this. It is possible to configure it only by application.properties? I was thinking about creating a new datasource with increased timeout predicted for flyway only, but im not sure if it is good solution and if it will work. The best solutioun for me would be something like covering flyway.migrate(); with @Transactional like example below

```
    @Transactional(timeout = FLYWAY_TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT)
    public FlywayMigrationStrategy flywayMigrationStrategy() {
        return flyway -> flyway.migrate();
    }
```

Comment: Which database are you using? Some allow connection properties to be set in the JDBC URL, which would clearly only affect Flyway and not other applications.

Comment: @JuliaHayward I am using Mysql

Comment: OK, I can't see a way to alter the timeout with JDBC. I don't know if the above code will work, if you try it (in a safe environment!) what happens? Is it the ALTER TABLE that is slow, or the subsequent updating of the new column, altering/populating indexes, etc?

Comment: it is just ```ALTER TABLE `TableName` ADD COLUMN `newColumnName` BIT(1) AFTER `existingColumnName`;``` Nothing more, but table contains 500k+ rows